# How to install Ambari in Hortonworks HDP?

Tags: centos, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am trying to install HortonWorks HDP manually on a CentOS box. I am following the instructions given on this page  http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_installing_manually_book/content/meet-min-system-requirements.html

I do not see any instruction on installing Apache Ambari. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions that you are looking at are for installing HDP manually, that means installing HDP without Ambari. You cannot have a manual installation with Ambari since Ambari is a tool for provisioning, managing and monitoring Hadoop clusters. If the cluster is configured manually it cannot be managed or monitored by Ambari.

If you do intend on having Ambari provision the cluster for you and the machine has access to the internet you can run the following commands:

For CentOS6

```
sudo wget -nv http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/2.x/updates/2.1.2/ambari.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo
sudo yum install ambari-server
sudo ambari-server setup
```

For CentOS7

```
sudo wget -nv http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7/2.x/updates/2.1.2/ambari.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo
sudo yum install ambari-server
sudo ambari-server setup
```

If the machine doesn't have access to the internet or if you need further information see the official HDP [documentation](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.2.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/ch_Installing_Ambari.html) for installation guidance.

Comment: Thanks cjackson. I would also like to understand, why the installation instruction on Hortonworks website is missing the instruction for installing ambari.?

Comment: They're not missing. The instructions that you are looking at is for installing HDP manually, that means installing HDP without Ambari. You cannot have a manual installation with Ambari. Ambari is a tool for provisioning, managing and monitoring Hadoop clusters. If the cluster is configured manually it cannot be managed or monitored by Ambari.

Comment: I thought, that by following the manual installation instruction, I will be able to build a 'non-vm sandbox' on a machine. Basically I do not want to run HDP as a sandbox (on a VM).  Maybe my understanding of HDP is not that good. Can you also clarify if I can have the same Sandbox setting on a standalone centOS machine (non-VM)?

Comment: If you follow the instructions I provided you can install Ambari on the machine and create an HDP stack that is like the sandbox. The configuration may be slightly different from the sandbox but it will be similar if you install all the services.